# How does inclusion threshold work in 2016 republican primary?

Tags: united-states, election

What happens to the votes received by candidates that do not meet the inclusion threshold? Are those votes effectively voided or counted for the front runner?

What about extreme cases
1) one candidate got 11% and all others got less than 10%
2) no candidate received more than 10%

Answer (score 2):

In the republican primaries in states that use the inclusion threshold, votes to candidates which don't meet that threshold are ceded to the person with the most votes. If 0 or 1 candidates meet the inclusion threshold then the primary is winner-take-all.

Comment: [Source for New Hampshire](http://www.npr.org/2016/02/08/465916627/why-a-vote-for-jeb-bush-could-be-a-vote-for-trump-in-the-new-hampshire-primary).

Comment: The result does not seem to be consistent with this rule. Is the delegate count always rounded up?

Comment: NH primary is proportional
(all based on statewide vote). The NPR article says proportional by statewide and by district.

Comment: The delegate count varies between the Dems and the Republicans. That article is most likely talking about the Democrats and not the Republicans.